# Displaying XML value using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery and XML.

I have got below XML format.

**Resource XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:link="http://www.example.com/tridion">
    <data name="LoginAccount" tcm="tcm:233-191754" type="Text">
        <value>Login to your Account</value>
    </data>
    <data name="Airport" tcm="tcm:233-191754" type="Text">
        <value>Airport</value>
    </data>
    <data name="BusinessClass" tcm="tcm:233-191754" type="Text">
        <value>Business</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

Now I have got JQuery where I am looking to get these values loaded first and then further use them in page, for example.

**JQuery Code Sample:**

```
// Dialog           
    $('#LoginLink').click(function(){
        $('#Login').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Login to your Account'
        });
        if($('#Login').is(':visible')) {
            hideSelect();
        } else {
            showSelect();
        }
    });
```

In above jquery code the text **'Login to your Account'** should come from my Resource XML as my application is multilingual.

I am looking to create such function in JQuery where I will just passing the **name attribute** value and which will fetch the actual values from XML, say for example.

**getDataFromResourceFile('LoginAccount');** should display **'Login to your Account'**

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to load up ur xml document into a variable:

```
var xmlData;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "resources.xml",// your xml file path
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
    xmlData = xml;// set the returned xml into a global variable
    }
});
```

Then

```
function getDataFromResourceFile(resourceKey)
{
  return $(xmlData).find('data[name=' + resourceKey + '] value').text();
}
```

That will do it for your XML file. You may have to check whether the XML data has loaded into the variable(xmlData) or not before using it.

**EDIT**:

Edited to Load the xml from server if it is not found.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlData;
    function getDataFromResourceFile(key)
    {
        if (xmlData == null)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "resources.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml)
                {
                    xmlData = xml;
                    return $(xmlData).find('data[name=' + key + '] value').text();
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return $(xmlData).find('data[name=' + key + '] value').text();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Omkar, I didn't understand what you are trying to say "You may have to check whether the XML data has loaded into the variable(xmlData) or not before using it." Can you please suggest with example.

Comment: since we are loading the xml via an ajax request(asynchronous) it may so happen that the file has not yet been received and we try to use $(xmlData).find('data[name=' + resourceKey + '] value').text(); That would cause an error since xmlData will be null.

Comment: So what type of check it required for this, please suggest!

Comment: @Thanks Omkar..for your help!